# A question about characteristic equation and digonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

how do we solve this problem is that eigen values or 0 and 1..but i am not sure
can any one help me this problem

Comment: Did you try the hints?  What did you get? $1$ is not an eigenvalue.  Jordan canonical form might be helpful, if you know about it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael..is that 0 is the only eigen value?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Can you see why?

Comment: @RobertIsrael..Coz A is nilpotent matrix

Comment: @suresh Sure, zero being the only eigenvalue is a consequence (actually an equivalent definition) of $A$ being nilpotent. I think he was looking for a reason/proof of this, not just a statement of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A then there exists an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$(say $v$) then $Av$=$\lambda v$, Now multiply by $A$, $22$ times both sides then we have $\lambda^{23}=0$ which implies $\lambda=0$, So $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$

Now characteristic polynomial of $A$ divides the polynomial $x^{23}=0$ and is of degree $5$, hence characteristic polynomial is $x^5=0$, hence by calyey-Hamilton theorem $A^5=0$

If $A$ is diagonalizable then it can be written in the form $P^{-1}BP$ where B is a diagonal matrix consisting of the eigenvalues of $A$ which implies $B=0$ which implies $A=0$. Now just try to find a non-zero matrix $A$ satisfying the conditions to get a counterexample. Try the example for $2$*$2$ matrices and generalise the example.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Not sure why they chose 23... it's pretty arbitrary. Michael Jordan, perhaps.

(a) Let $v$ be any eigenvector and $\lambda$ its eigenvalue. Then you have

$$O = A^{23}v = \lambda^{23}v$$ What can you conclude about $\lambda$?

(b) should be easy if you know the characteristic poly has degree 5 and the theorem they're hinting at.

(c) Actually you don't have enough information to answer this question. They probably meant to state that $A$ is not the zero matrix. However, you can prove given the information above, that if $A$ is diagonalizable then it must be the zero matrix. (Hint: you know the eigenvalues from part a. If it were diagonal, what would it look like?)